# Update value only if in another column it says “Update” in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have created a function called =SalePrice that will markup the values found on "Cost Price" column by a percentage for a product.

Now I want to be able to check on an adjacent column called UpdatePrice to see if the product's sale price must remain unchanged.

So I want to create a function that will do:

```
IF(UpdatePrice = "Update Price",SalePrice,KeepOldValue)
```

[image: Example Table]

So I want to update values in column F only if in V column = "Update Price", else the value in F column should remain unchanged.

How would you do that?

Comment: How your original function is relevant to your problem? What you've tried to create that function? What's the specific step you've problem with?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check about the UpdatePrice? Can you clarify with an example what you mean by `UpdatePrice = "Update Price"`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a table, which is a good start. Add some column names, like UpdatePrice instead of CustomField10. Then use those column names in a formula, like `=IF([@UpdatePrice]="Update Price", [@SalePrice], [@FullPrice])`.

Comment: Well, I can't really change the column names since they are needed as is to update the company's ERP inventory. Also,  I guess you are proposing a new column named FullPrice to store the old values first?

Comment: You don't need to change the column names. I suggested the change to make the formula easy to read. It's a nice feature of tables that column names appear in a formula. Also, you don't need a new column for full price if that value is in the "Cost Price" column. (I can't tell from your screen image.)

Comment: The way I handled it was with a helper column, that would store the old values first on a sheet named Data on columnD and then use a formula that would check if ([@UpdatePrice]="Update Price",SalePrice,Data!D2). This is done with a macro. SalePrice is a named formula that will do all the markup required for the price.

Answer (score 0):

So, What I did was:

Create a macro that

```
'Select UpdatePrices sheet.
    Sheets("UpdatePrices").Select
'Select All the rows containing values and delete them.
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C1"
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
'Select the ERP sheet with the latest values and copy paste them to the UpdatePrices Sheet
    Sheets("ManagerImportSheet").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C1"
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("UpdatePrices").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C1"
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'Select the Old Sale Prices and copy them.
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C1"
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Range("UpdatePrices[[#Headers],[Code]]").Select
    Range("UpdatePrices[SalePrice]").Select
    'Range("F1476").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
'Go to Data Sheet and Paste them for later use in formula
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C3"
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'Clear contents of Sale Price and Cost Price columns
    Sheets("UpdatePrices").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C1"
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Range("UpdatePrices[[#Headers],[Code]]").Select
    Range("UpdatePrices[CustomFields.8220bcd8c4284ee9b653cced0445a0cd]").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'Enter the named formula to calculate the new CostPrices.
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C20"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CostPrice"
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C6"
'Enter a formula that will check the "Update Price" Column named '[@[CustomFields.49d90e39488947ef899044e3c56a23f5] and if it is equal to
' "Update Price" then use the named formula SalePrice else, copy the old price into
' Place from the Data sheet.
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF([@[CustomFields.49d90e39488947ef899044e3c56a23f5]]=""Update Price"",SalePrice,Data!RC[-3])"
```

What is left to do is probably lock the appropriate sheets/cells.